# Hibernate Reverse Engineering error

Tags: mysql, hibernate

I need some help in solving this Hibernate error.

My environment is:

- Eclipse Kepler Service Release 1
- Hibernate 3.6.9
- MySql 5.5

This is my hibernate.cfg.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
"-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD 3.0//EN"
"http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">

<hibernate-configuration>
 <session-factory>
   <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.password">LexoR</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/s2me</property>
  <property name="hibernate.connection.username">root</property>
  <property name="hibernate.default_schema">s2me</property>
  <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
 </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

This is the hibernate.reveng.xml:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <!DOCTYPE hibernate-reverse-engineering PUBLIC "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Reverse Engineering DTD 3.0//EN" "http://hibernate.sourceforge.net/hibernate-reverse-engineering-3.0.dtd" >

    <hibernate-reverse-engineering>
      <table-filter match-schema="s2me" match-name=".*"/>
    </hibernate-reverse-engineering>

And the error log whne I try to generate the POJO files:

org.hibernate.console.HibernateConsoleRuntimeException: Received a NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath is incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class

org.hibernate.console.HibernateConsoleRuntimeException: Received a NoClassDefFoundError, probably the console configuration classpath is incomplete or contains conflicting versions of the same class
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate3_6.console.ConsoleExtension3_6.launchExporters(ConsoleExtension3_6.java:149)
    at org.hibernate.eclipse.launch.CodeGenerationLaunchDelegate.launch(CodeGenerationLaunchDelegate.java:270)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:858)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.core.LaunchConfiguration.launch(LaunchConfiguration.java:707)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin.buildAndLaunch(DebugUIPlugin.java:1018)
    at org.eclipse.debug.internal.ui.DebugUIPlugin$8.run(DebugUIPlugin.java:1222)
    at org.eclipse.core.internal.jobs.Worker.run(Worker.java:53)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Could not initialize class org.hibernate.cfg.reveng.OverrideRepository
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate3_6.console.ConsoleExtension3_6$3.execute(ConsoleExtension3_6.java:249)
    at org.hibernate.console.execution.DefaultExecutionContext.execute(DefaultExecutionContext.java:63)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate3_6.HibernateExtension3_6.execute(HibernateExtension3_6.java:201)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate3_6.console.ConsoleExtension3_6.buildConfiguration(ConsoleExtension3_6.java:239)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate3_6.console.ConsoleExtension3_6.runExporters(ConsoleExtension3_6.java:169)
    at org.jboss.tools.hibernate3_6.console.ConsoleExtension3_6.launchExporters(ConsoleExtension3_6.java:126)
    ... 6 more
```

My Google searches have not turned up any help. 
Any help?
Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Your reverse engineering tool already has hibernate jar and is conflicting with your hibernate jar. I am aware of what kind of reverse engineering tool you are using. I am guessing it's JBoss Reverse Engineering tool? It's better to use other alternatives like MyEclipse or Intellij. This can save you a lot of time with a small amount of money.

Comment: I tried removing all jars from my project and I get the same error as the person above. It has something to do with the options of the plugin itself.